# Can't navigate to specific anchor in Angular 4 route

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have two separate controllers.
When I click on a certain link from one controller, I want to be redirect to a specific anchor tag in the other one.

I'm trying to do this by passing as a queryParam to the router the anchor tag.

However, when I try to retrieve it on the destination component, the parameter is undefined.

Here's what I'm doing in my source component:

```
this.router.navigate(['home',{
queryParams: {anchor: 'about'}}])
```

And here is how I try to retrieve the parameter in the destination Component:

```
this.anchor = this.route.queryParams['anchor']
```

But it's always undefined.

The redirection works anyway, but of course I can't go to the specific anchor.

Comment: Shouldn't you be *subscribing* to the query params observable? Please give a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this: https://angular.io/guide/router#activated-route

You should be using queryParamMap, which is an observable. You must subscribe to it, ideally in the ngOnInit method, and retrieve the value for your queryParam over there.

As noted in the link I referenced, the use of queryParams is discouraged. Also, you're not using it correctly in any case. It is an observable that must be subscribed to, not an array.

Here's an example

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.queryParamMap.subscribe(queryParams => {
      this.anchor = queryParams['anchor'];
    });
  }
```